# Docker fails to kill containers under high load (selenium/node-docker)

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Using version 4.8.3 of selenium/node-docker container and selenium grid, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-146-generic x86_64)

With a high load (in our case, there are 100 parallel containers/sessions), after 10-15 minutes, the docker starts to get dumb and fall off according to the default timeout of 10 seconds when trying to kill containers of chrome:

```
Apr 19 11:59:43 dockerd[33841]: time="2023-04-19T11:59:43.980407954Z" level=error msg="Container failed to exit within 10s of kill - trying direct SIGKILL" container=82e58732e70fa9dd242747967c88a384b6e241c9a8ff9a51f51726b13021f412 error="context deadline exceeded"

Apr 19 11:59:38 dockerd[33841]: time="2023-04-19T11:59:38.023229398Z" level=error msg="error killing container: context deadline exceeded" container=633fd2579e60039974f40d17664cf99e786d151871a23477ed513a2d224e3146 error="tried to kill container, but did not receive an exit event"

08:39:52.317 WARN [Container.stop] - Unable to stop container: Unable to stop container: 2d13158bf2857fc02c5b2bbdc4fea60ce1074e80b28da2531dc716e2177477c0
cannot stop container: 2d13158bf2857fc02c5b2bbdc4fea60ce1074e80b28da2531dc716e2177477c0: tried to kill container, but did not receive an exit event
org.openqa.selenium.docker.DockerException: Unable to stop container: 2d13158bf2857fc02c5b2bbdc4fea60ce1074e80b28da2531dc716e2177477c0
cannot stop container: 2d13158bf2857fc02c5b2bbdc4fea60ce1074e80b28da2531dc716e2177477c0: tried to kill container, but did not receive an exit event
        at org.openqa.selenium.docker.v1_41.DockerMessages.throwIfNecessary(DockerMessages.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.docker.v1_41.StopContainer.apply(StopContainer.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.docker.v1_41.V141Docker.stopContainer(V141Docker.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.docker.Container.stop(Container.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.docker.DockerSession.stop(DockerSession.java:70)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.stop(SessionSlot.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.stopTimedOutSession(LocalNode.java:285)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.processPendingNotifications(LocalCache.java:1814)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.runUnlockedCleanup(LocalCache.java:3467)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.postWriteCleanup(LocalCache.java:3443)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.remove(LocalCache.java:3077)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.remove(LocalCache.java:4251)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.invalidate(LocalCache.java:4891)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.stop(LocalNode.java:706)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.executeWebDriverCommand(LocalNode.java:585)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.ForwardWebDriverCommand.execute(ForwardWebDriverCommand.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute.handle(Route.java:373)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.execute(Node.java:255)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:44)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Container has only one process:

```
docker top 7204f5af2ec9
UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
1200 2455652 2451068 0 12:20 ? 00:00:02 /usr/bin/fluxbox -display :99.0
```

When running 40 parallel sessions, this problem was not observed.
Also in the tests there is a delay in waiting for the browser to close up to 2 minutes.

What could be the problem? At the same time, the processor is enough (112 CPUs)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.